# jboss- Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"xxx.war\")]"

Tags: jboss7.x

I am getting error as

> Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"crafartweb.war\")]"

I am using jboss 7.1 . How to resolve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: More context please. Is this when you're starting the server, when you attempt to deploy something?

Comment: It is possible you have deployed your war to the jboss deployments folder and try to deploy it again from your IDE. If that is the case, delete the war in jboss/standalone/deployments folder, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it looks like this was caused by the following sequence:

1. Using IntelliJ to deploy a war file to JBoss
2. Manually copying a .war file and manually starting JBoss.

This was due to how IntelliJ apparently updates the standalone.xml file, adding a  element that points to the .war file in IntelliJ. The warning comes from the conflict of having the same .war file in the deployments folder as is specified by the deployment element in standalone.xml.